# Objeto de acesso a dados - DAO

Tags: java, design-pattern

Estou aprendendo padrões de projeto e aplicando em um CRUD , dentro do DAO só posso deixa estes código referente aos SQL?

```
    public class UsuarioDAO {
        private Connection con = ConexaoFactory.getConnection();

    public void cadastrar(Usuario usuario) {
        String sql = "insert into usuario(nome, login,senha)values(?,?,?)";
        try(PreparedStatement preparestatement = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {

            preparestatement.setString(1, usuario.getNome()); //substitui o ? pelo dado do usuario
            preparestatement.setString(2, usuario.getLogin());
            preparestatement.setString(3, usuario.getSenha());

            //executando comando sql

            preparestatement.execute();
            preparestatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void aleterar(Usuario usuario){
        String sql = "update usuario set nome = ?, login = ?, senha = ? where idusuario = ?";
        try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql)){

            preparedStatement.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, usuario.getLogin());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, usuario.getSenha());
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, usuario.getIdUsuario());
            preparedStatement.execute();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void excluir(Usuario usuario){
        String sql = "delete from usuario where idusuario = ?";
        try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql)){
            preparedStatement.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já que disse que está aprendendo padrões de projeto começo com uma observação, você está deixando de fora da sua implementação um ator fundamental no padrão, a interface. [Veja aqui](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm).

Sobre o que pode ou não haver dentro de do DAO, com certeza não é apenas código referente ao SQL, de forma bem básica e simples por 2 motivos:

1) Dao não é, necessáriamente, "comunicador" de banco de dados. Data Access Object trata de acesso a objetos que chamamos de dados, mas é perfeitamente possível que isso não tenha nenhum vínculo com banco de dados. Um exemplo, uma aplicação que trata informações de resultados de exames laboratoriais, as máquinas geram arquivos xml, json e outros padrões (as vezes proprietários), seu DAO jamais faria uma sql.

2) Ainda que se trate de uma aplicação com foco em banco de dados relacionais seu DAO é responsável por fazer com que seu sistema possa funcionar sem conhecer/acessar o banco. Isso implica, por vezes, fazer "traduções", adaptações, conversões, etc; tarefas que também não demandam interação via SQL.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado, bem didático e explicativo seu comentário.